# Image view во вью пейджер некорректное поведение onResume

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

В проекте в одной из вкладок шаблон с Вью Пейджером на 2 фрагмента. 
Там сверху `AppBarLayout` > `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.
В нем `ImageView` которая показывает картинку в зависимости от позиции пейджера 1 или 2.
**Проблема** в том, что при повторном переключении на этот фрагмент, если была активна вторая вкладка, когда срабатывает onResume, сначала ставится картинка по умолчанию, а затем быстро меняется на 2.

Вот фрагмент:

```
private ImageView image_header;
private Handler handler = new Handler();

 @Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_fragment, container, false);
    image_header = view.findViewById(R.id.image_header);
    image_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_taxi);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    PagerAdapter1 pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter1(getChildFragmentManager());
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        viewPager = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
    }
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    tabLayout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            switch (position){
                case 0:  image_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_taxi);
                    break;
                case 1: image_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_city);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {
        }
    });
}
```

Я понимаю что при повторном обращении происходит дефолтная установка
из вызова `image_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_taxi);`
А потом считывается позиция и срабатывает `onPageSelected`.
Но если картинку не устанавливать таким образом, то при первом запуске она не будет установлена вообще(

Но может кто нибудь объяснит как избежать данной ситуации?

Comment: Попробуйте в `onCreateView` `image_header.setImageResource(0);` или `image_header.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);` Кроме того в xml описании тоже не должно быть установлено ничего. А "мигает" у вас потому что сначала в `onCreateView` вы проставляете картинку "такси" и в `handler.postDelayed` через 200 миллисекунд вы ставите другую картинку.

Comment: С другой стороны, что мешает вам добавить в активити переменную `int currentPosition`, и в `onActivityCreated` считывать её `((MyActivity)getActivity()).currentPosition` , и устанавливать нужное изображение?